# How can I make a dynamic info page with both V-for and V-if?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, for-loop

**Hi guys, I just tried to implement this layout here:**

[image]

So basically this company has different categories of services, which then have different sub options and then it they have details about them specifically.

My JSON looks like this:

```
    {
        "services": [{
                "name": "COVID-19",
                "options": [
                    "COVID-19 Temperature Screening System"
                ],
                "information": {
                    "images": [
                        "http://placekitten.com/300/300"
                    ],
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Qui, in."
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Home",
                "options": [
                    "Camera",
                    "Fire Alarm",
                    "Motion Sensor"
                ],
                "information": {
                    "images": [
                        "http://placekitten.com/300/300"
                    ],
                    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Qui, in."
                }
            },
....
```

So far the problem im having here is that I want to use a v-if and a v-for together to change which product is being displayed depending what the user clicks on. It throws this error:

> 26:11  error    The 'this.JSON' expression inside 'v-for' directive
> should be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered
> array instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'

Can anybody help me out with using the computed property to do this as I'm confused to what that means, here is the services page:

```
<template>
  <div class="services">
    <div class="header services__header">
      <h1 :class="$mq">Services</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="services__services-container">
      <div class="services__services-container__category-selection">
        <!-- GENERATE CATEGORIES -->
        <div
          class="services__services-container__category-selection__category"
          v-for="(item, index) in this.JSON"
          :key="`category-${index}`"
          :class="$mq"
        >
          <input type="radio" :name="item.name" :value="item.name" v-model="currentCategory" />
          <label :for="item.name">{{item.name}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- GENERATE SERVICES -->
      <div class="services__services-container__service-selection">
        <div
          class="services__services-container__service-selection__service"
          v-for="(item, index) in this.JSON"
          :key="`service-${index}`"
          :class="$mq"
          v-if="currentCategory === item.name"
        >
        <!-- ^^^ THIS V-IF IS NOT ALLOWED -->
          <div
            class="services__services-container__service-selection__service__wrapper"
            v-for="(option, index) in item.options"
            :key="`option-${index}`"
            :class="$mq"
          >
            <input type="radio" :name="option" :value="option" v-model="currentService" />
            <label :for="option">{{option.optionName}}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- GENERATE DESCRIPTIONS -->
      <div class="services__services-container__product-description">
        <div
          class="services__services-container__product-description__description"
          v-for="(item, index) in this.JSON"
          :key="`service-${index}`"
          :class="$mq"
        >
          <div v-for="(option, index) in item.options" :key="`option-${index}`" :class="$mq">
            <img :src="option.images" alt />
            <p>{{option.description}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import services from "@/JSON/services.json";
export default {
  name: "Services",
  data: function() {
    return {
      JSON: [],
      currentCategory: "",
      currentService: ""
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    //TO TEST
    this.JSON = services.services;
    this.JSON.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
    });
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/scss/variables.scss";
@import "@/scss/button.scss";
@import "@/scss/header.scss";
@import "@/scss/input.scss";
.services {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 15vh auto auto auto;

  &__services-container {
    padding: 2rem;
    & input {
      margin-right: 0.5rem;
    }

    &__category-selection {
      background-color: $colour-green;
      padding: 1rem;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    &__service-selection {
      padding: 1rem;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      &__service {
        background-color: $colour-blue;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }
    }

    &__product-description {
      background-color: $new-service;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      &__description {
        & img {
          margin-bottom: 1rem;
        }
        background-color: pink;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

My script section:

```
<script>
import services from "@/JSON/services.json";
export default {
  name: "Services",
  data: function() {
    return {
      JSON: [],
      currentCategory: "Home",
      currentService: ""
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    //TO TEST
    this.JSON = services.services;
    this.JSON.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go that way, that the chosen radio is the item itself like this:

```
  <div class="services">
    <div class="header services__header">
      {{currentCategory}}
      <h1 :class="$mq">Services</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="services__services-container">
      <div class="services__services-container__category-selection">
        <!-- GENERATE CATEGORIES -->
        <div class="services__services-container__category-selection__category" v-for="(item, index) in services" :key="`category-${index}`" :class="$mq">
          <input type="radio" :name="item.name" :value="item" v-model="currentCategory" />
          <label :for="item.name">{{item.name}}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- GENERATE SERVICES -->
      <div class="services__services-container__service-selection" v-if="currentCategory!=null">
        <div class="services__services-container__service-selection__service" :class="$mq">
          <!-- ^^^ THIS V-IF IS NOT ALLOWED -->
          <div class="services__services-container__service-selection__service__wrapper" v-for="(option, index) in currentCategory.options" :key="`option-${index}`" :class="$mq">
            {{option}}
            <input type="radio" :name="option" :value="option" v-model="currentService" />
            <label :for="option">{{option.optionName}}</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- GENERATE DESCRIPTIONS -->
      {{currentService}}
      <div class="services__services-container__product-description" v-if="currentService!=null">
        <div class="services__services-container__product-description__description" :class="$mq">
          <div :class="$mq">
            <img :src="currentCategory.information.images" alt />
            <p>{{currentCategory.information.description}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have checked your code and it's giving me a error of: TypeError: "_vm.currentCategory.information is undefined". How do I model the radio as an item itself in the data method?

Comment: Never mind, I changed the currentCategory in the last sections img and p to currentService and it works. Thanks so much! genius

Answer (score 0):

> 26:11 error The 'this.JSON' expression inside 'v-for' directive should
> be replaced with a computed property that returns filtered array
> instead. You should not mix 'v-for' with 'v-if'

What is meant by that error message is, you should apply your v-if statement (which acts as a filter of the services) within a computed property, rather than in the template.

so instead of this:

```html
<template>
  <div
          class="services__services-container__service-selection__service"
          v-for="(item, index) in this.JSON"
          :key="`service-${index}`"
          :class="$mq"
          v-if="currentCategory === item.name"
        >
</template>
```

try this:

```html
<template>
  <div
          class="services__services-container__service-selection__service"
          v-for="(item, index) in filteredJson"
          :key="`service-${index}`"
          :class="$mq"
        >
</template>
```

so your script would need the computed property "filteredJson":

```html
<script>
import services from "@/JSON/services.json";
export default {
  name: "Services",
  data: function() {
    return {
      JSON: [],
      currentCategory: "",
      currentService: ""
    };
  },
  created: function() {
    //TO TEST
    this.JSON = services.services;
    this.JSON.forEach(element => {
      console.log(element);
    });
  },
  computed: {
    filteredJson() {
      return this.JSON.filter(item=> currentCategory === item.name);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```